# Update model Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm a new in Realm and ask you to help me.
I created the model:

```
class UserModel: Object {

    dynamic var email = ""
    dynamic var facebook_id = ""
    dynamic var google_id = ""
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var photo = ""
    dynamic var someinfo = ""
    dynamic var twitter_id = "" 

}
```

When I login to app, I can see my info on UserProfileController. Also I have a EditProfileController where I can change some info about myself. So when I successfully change it, I want to update my Realm model, and try to do this:

```
    let realm = try! Realm()

    try! realm.write {
        realm.create(UserModel.self, value: ["name": self.editEmail.text!, "email": self.editEmail.text!], update: true)
    }
```

But unfortunately I see this message:

```
''UserModel' does not have a primary key and can not be updated'
```

What if I want to update a few property at the same time? 
Can I do this with primaryKey? Or...
How it possible to update Realm model without primaryKey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lie in this `update: true`, it's used to automatically replace object that have the same primary key in your realm, if your object don't have primary key, set `update` to `false` then it will work and always create new object

Comment: Thank you for you reply! I replace 'true' to 'false'. And that error no longer appears. But my model doesn't update...

Comment: If you want it to update instead of create new, you have to give it primary key and set update to true, or fetch the object and remove it first, then create new object, it's kinda a lot of work but it's how it works

Comment: I understand, you. Tip me please! How I can to update more than one property at the same time with primeryKey in one model?

Comment: Just replace all of the object's properties then do a realm write (if you have primary key then don't change the primary key), thats all, you dont have to update each property separately

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a primary key for your `UserModel`.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys

Comment: Ok. But, What if I want to update more than one property at the same time?

Comment: I probably fetch `UserModel` from `Realm` then update.